# helmsman stuck after displaying on debug helm plugin list

Tags: gitlab, runner

I'm trying to use helmsman in gitlab runner dind.

```
helmsman --apply -f _dsf.yaml --verbose --debug

 _          _ 
| |        | | 
| |__   ___| |_ __ ___  ___ _ __ ___   __ _ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ | '_ ` _ \/ __| '_ ` _ \ / _` | '_ \ 
| | | |  __/ | | | | | \__ \ | | | | | (_| | | | | 
|_| |_|\___|_|_| |_| |_|___/_| |_| |_|\__,_|_| |_| version: v3.16.3
A Helm-Charts-as-Code tool.

2023-09-25 20:55:16 INFO: Checking Helm version
2023-09-25 20:55:16 DEBUG: helm version --short --client
2023-09-25 20:55:16 INFO: Helm client version: v3.12.0+gc9f554d
2023-09-25 20:55:16 INFO: Checking Helm version
2023-09-25 20:55:16 DEBUG: helm version --short --client
2023-09-25 20:55:16 INFO: Checking kubectl version
2023-09-25 20:55:16 DEBUG: kubectl version --output=json --client
2023-09-25 20:55:17 INFO: kubectl client version: v1.25.11
2023-09-25 20:55:17 INFO: Validating that [ diff ] is installed
2023-09-25 20:55:17 DEBUG: helm plugin list
2023-09-25 20:55:17 INFO: Substitution of env variables enabled
2023-09-25 20:55:17 INFO: Substitution of SSM variables enabled
```

And it stays like this until gitlab runner closes the job. On local machine or docker(non dind) its working fine.

```
helmsman --apply -f dsf.yaml --verbose --debug

 _          _ 
| |        | | 
| |__   ___| |_ __ ___  ___ _ __ ___   __ _ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ | '_ ` _ \/ __| '_ ` _ \ / _` | '_ \ 
| | | |  __/ | | | | | \__ \ | | | | | (_| | | | | 
|_| |_|\___|_|_| |_| |_|___/_| |_| |_|\__,_|_| |_| version: v3.16.3
A Helm-Charts-as-Code tool.

2023-09-25 21:02:36 INFO: Checking Helm version
2023-09-25 21:02:36 DEBUG: helm version --short --client
2023-09-25 21:02:36 INFO: Helm client version: v3.12.0+gc9f554d
2023-09-25 21:02:36 INFO: Checking Helm version
2023-09-25 21:02:36 DEBUG: helm version --short --client
2023-09-25 21:02:36 INFO: Checking kubectl version
2023-09-25 21:02:36 DEBUG: kubectl version --output=json --client
2023-09-25 21:02:36 INFO: kubectl client version: v1.25.11
2023-09-25 21:02:36 INFO: Validating that [ diff ] is installed
2023-09-25 21:02:36 DEBUG: helm plugin list
2023-09-25 21:02:36 INFO: Substitution of env variables enabled
2023-09-25 21:02:36 INFO: Substitution of SSM variables enabled
2023-09-25 21:02:36 INFO: Parsed [[ dsf.yaml ]] successfully and found [ 11 ] apps
```

I think is something related to type of runner because is docker executor. With runner shell executor is passing that step, but we are limited to number of commands.

To make helmsman work in gitlab runner docker executor.